# Invoke R script on AWS Lambda from NodeJS

Tags: r, node.js, amazon-web-services, lambda, rserve

As a result of several hours of unfruitful searches, I am posting this question. 
I suppose it is a duplicate of this one: 
[How do you run RServe on AWS Lambda with NodeJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42543995/how-do-you-run-rserve-on-aws-lambda-with-nodejs)
But since it seems that the author of that question did not accomplish his/her goal successfully, I am going to try again.

**What I currently have:**

A NodeJS server, that invokes an R script through [Rserve](https://www.rforge.net/Rserve/) and passes data to evaluate through [node-rio](https://github.com/albertosantini/node-rio).

Function responsible for that looks like this:

```
const R = (arg1, arg2) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
          const args = {
            arg1, arg2
          };
          //send data to Rserve to evaluate
          rio.$e({
            filename: path.resolve('./r-scripts/street.R'),
            entrypoint: 'run',
            data: args,
          })
            .then((data)=>{
              resolve(JSON.parse(data));
            })
            .catch((err)=>{
              reject(`err: ${err}`);
            });
        });
    };
```

And this works just fine. I am sending data over to my R instance and getting results back into my server.

**What I am ultimately trying to achieve:**

Every request seems to spawn its own R workspace, which has a considerable memory overhead. Thus, serving even hundreds of concurrent requests using this approach is impossible, as my AWS EC2 runs out of memory pretty quickly. 
So, I am looking for a way to deploy all the memory intensive parts to AWS Lambda and thus get rid of the memory overhead.

I guess, the specific question in my case is if there is a way to package R and Rserve together with NodeJS lambda function. Or if there is a way for me to get convinced that this approach won't work using lambda and I should try to look for an alternative.

Note: I cannot use anything other than R, since these are external R scripts, that I have to invoke from my server.

Thanks in advance!